# reading an object from stream

Tags: object, stream

I'm trying to read an object `ChatMassage` from the stream and to print a message (which this object contains) with its method `getMassage()`. It prints a message the first time but next time it always prints the first message. What is wrong?

Here is an example of the code:

```
while(keepGoing){

    System.out.println("Client: " + ((ChatMassage) in.readObject()).getMassage() + "\n" );

}
```

ChatMassage class:

```
public class ChatMassage implements Serializable {

    String msg, recipientName = null;
    String senderName = "None";

    public void setMassage(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public void setRecipientName(String recName) {
        recipientName = recName;
    }

    public String getMassage() {
        return msg;
    }

    public String getRecipientName() {
        return recipientName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(String name) {
        senderName = name;
    }

    public String getSenderName() {
        return senderName;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in this method:

```
public void setMassage(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
```

I don't know if that can be a problem, but try changing the parameter to something like "new_msg". I think it confuses the "this.msg" with "msg".